# how to insert redundant data

Tags: postgresql, insert

I am inserting data, which **ipaddress_client column** and **analysis_route column** should be written with the same data from PHP input **(redundant)** following the total row of the geomjson&id_esb column. 
 here is the code:

```
INSERT INTO user_route(ipaddress_client, geom_route, analysis_route, id_shelter_destiny)
  VALUES ( '$ipaddress', (select geom_json from analysis), 'nearest facility', (select id_esb from analysis))
```

but I got this error

> ERROR:  lebih dari satu baris dikembalikan oleh subquery yang digunakan sebagai ekspresi
> , SQL state: 21000

**Translation**:
Error: more than one row returned by the subquery used as an expression

Can somebody tell me how to write redundant data in this case?

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer from seeing this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19227699/16528054)

```
INSERT INTO user_route(ipaddress_client, geom_route, analysis_route, id_shelter_destiny)
SELECT '$ipaddress', geom_json, 'nearest facility', id_esb 
from analysis;
```